# Create a constant session in Meteor javascript

Tags: javascript, session, meteor, cart

I am building web store using Meteor and having issues with adding items to my cart. Right now, each cart is uniquely identified by a Session ID. However, if I have two browser tabs open, each tab will have its own Session ID. Therefore, is there a method or technique I can use to create a Session ID that is constant across all browser tabs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have two option here:

1. Save on temporary collection on server where it will persist across browsers / devices.
2. Use localStrorage where it will persist acroos tab on the same browser. Take a look [AmplifyJS Store](http://amplifyjs.com/) and [meteor-persistent-session](https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session/).